# Given $1010^2=3077^2 \pmod {3551}$ find the factors of $3551$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am revising for my exams this coming summer and I came across this style of question in my past papers.

$1010^2=3077^2 \pmod {3551}$, we are told that $N=3551$ is the product of two prime numbers. What knowledge do I need to be able to find the factors of $3551$ from this alone?

Comment: What is $N\,\!$?

Comment: @MiloBrandt I'm pretty sure they mean that $N = 3551$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $a^2\equiv b^2 \mod N$, and $a\not\equiv \pm b\mod N$, then you can find a factor of $N$ by computing $\gcd(a-b,N)$. In this case, $1010\not\equiv\pm 3077\mod 3551$, so we get 
$$
\gcd(3077-1010,3551)=53
$$
which gives us a proper factor of $3551$.

To see why this works, note that if $a^2\equiv b^2\mod N$, then $cN=a^2-b^2$, or alternatively, $cN=(a+b)(a-b)$. Thus $N$ divides $(a-b)(a+b)$, but does not divide either $(a+b)$ or $(a-b)$ by the hypothesis that $a\not\equiv \pm b\mod N$. Thus computing the $\gcd$ of $N$ and $(a-b)$ will get you a nontrivial factor of $N$.